# Why is my wsl folder/vscode bugged after having many (150k) on files in it?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have process some images, over 70k at number. After doing so, and being left with 150k(50GB) files, everything worked fine with my VSCode.
Today, I opened it and got a "Reconnecting to WSL: Ubuntu" when I wanted to use the console. This persisted every time I opened VSCode, making it unusable.

I removed all the files (deleted half and the other half was moved elsewhere). This didn't fix my problem.
The error stopped after recreating the project in a folder with a different name. If I delete the folder, and recreated the project in a folder with the same name, the error occurs again.